# Having a foreach loop in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

**Controller:**

```
public function leaderboard() {
    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('images', 'users.id', '=', 'images.user_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('users.*, COUNT(*) AS totalUploads'))
        ->orderby('totalUploads', 'desc')
        ->groupby('users.id')
        ->take(50)
        ->get();

    return View::make('leaderboard')->with('users', $users);
}
```

**View:**

```
    <tbody>
        <?php $i = 0; $rank = 0; $lastCount = null; ?>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <?php $i++; if ($user->totalUploads != $lastCount) { $rank = $i; } else { $rank = null; } ?>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $rank }}</td>
            <td><a href="user/{{ $user->username }}">{{ $user->username }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $user->totalUploads }}</td>
        </tr>
        <?php $lastCount = $user->totalUploads; ?>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

**Current Output:** *(dashes denote `<tr>`'s)*

```
Rank  Name  Uploads
------------------- 
   1  Joe       103
-------------------   
   2  Dan        99
-------------------   
   3  Pam        87
-------------------   
      Kim        87
-------------------  
      Bob        87
-------------------      
   6  Mel        60
```

**Goal Output:** *(dashes denote `<tr>`'s)*

```
Rank  Name  Uploads
------------------- 
   1  Joe       103
-------------------   
   2  Dan        99
-------------------   
   3  Pam        87
      Kim        87
      Bob        87
-------------------      
   6  Mel        60
```

Essentially I would like to add a foreach or some other kind of loop that will separate users by `<br />` in the same `<tr>` if `$user->totalUploads` is tied.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

```
<tbody>
        <?php $i = 0; $rank = 0; $lastCount = null; ?>
        @for($i=0; $i<count($users); $i++)

        <?php $user = $users[$i]; 
            if ($user->totalUploads != $lastCount) { $rank = $i; } else { $rank = null; } 
        ?>

         <tr>
            <td>{{ $rank }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="user/{{ $user->username }}">{{ $user->username }}</a>

                <?php $j=0; ?>

                @if(isset($user[$i+1]) && $users[$i+1]->totalUploads == $user->totalUploads)

                    @for($j=$i+1; $j<count($users)&&$users[$j]->totalUploads == $user->totalUploads; $j++)

                        <a href="user/{{ $users[$j]->username }}">{{ $users[$j]->username }}</a>


                    @endfor

                @endif

            </td>
            <td>{{ $user->totalUploads }}

                @if($j>0)

                    @for($k=0; $k<$j-$i; $k++)

                        {{ $user->totalUploads }}


                    @endfor

                @endif

            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php 
        $i=$i+$j;
        $lastCount = $user->totalUploads; ?>
        @endfor
    </tbody>
```

Please note i didn't tested this code, even though this seems complicated, i think it will work

**OLD VERSION**

You can try something like :

```
 <tbody>
        <?php $i = 0; $rank = 0; $lastCount = null; ?>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <?php $i++; if ($user->totalUploads != $lastCount) { $rank = $i; } else { $rank = null; } ?>
        @if($rank) <tr> @else <br/> @endif
            <td>{{ $rank }}</td>
            <td><a href="user/{{ $user->username }}">{{ $user->username }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $user->totalUploads }}</td>
        @if($rank)</tr> @endif
        <?php $lastCount = $user->totalUploads; ?>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Essentially adding a blade if condition in the foreach. If the rank isn't changed ( meaning it's on the same "level" , you don't output the  but output a 
 . The closing  tag will only be applied when rank is not null ( not on same level )

Comment: This breaks the markup since it will show up as `<br /><td></td><br />`